# How to access a named List Style in MS Word from VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

If I create a multilevel list style in MS Word I can give it a name. However, when I use VBA to access the `ActiveDocument.ListTemplates` collection and I look at the `Name` property on `ListTemplate` objects the name that I defined is not indicated.

Actually, I found that the `Name` property of a `ListTemplate` object refers to the **ListNum field list name** in the **Define new Multilevel list** dialog.

It seems that the `ActiveDocument.ListTemplates` property is a collection of list templates, some of which are related to the lists that appear in the document, others are related to list styles and some are members of the collection despite not being used in the document at all.

So, does anyone know if it is possible to define a new List Style using the Word GUI, name it (e.g., "MyTemp") and then access it from the VBA code by referencing that name, e.g.:

```
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel _
    listTemplate:=ActiveDocument.ListTemplates("MyTemp"), _
    ApplyLevel:=1
```

Comment: Try `ActiveDocument.Styles("MyTemp").ListTemplate`

Comment: Also, your usage of `ActiveDocument` and `Selection` is hinting me that your code are most likely full of these and you should avoid that. Most of the time you do not need to select anything to do something in VBA. @Neits

Comment: @RaymondWu, thanks a lot, it happens that I had a 'lightbulb' moment just after posting this question and I came to the same answer. However, if you want to post an answer I will upvote it and mark it as a solution.

Comment: @RaymondWu, true, my document is polluted with ```ListTemplate``` objects in the ```ActiveDocument.ListTemplates``` collection.

Comment: Good for you! If `ActiveDocument` is actually the document that runs the code, you can use `ThisDocument` instead. otherwise you can declare a `Document` object variable, set `ActiveDocument` to it at the start then refer to that variable for the rest of the code. I won't be posting an answer so you can accept your own answer after.. few days (I forgot how many days)

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading [Shauna Kelly's guide to setting up numbering](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the List Style that we define is a member of the `ActiveDocument.Styles` collection, so the list template can be accessed by `ActiveDocument.Styles("MyStyle").ListTemplate`.

Therefore:

```
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel _
        ListTemplate:=ActiveDocument.Styles("MyStyle").ListTemplate, _
        ApplyLevel:=1
```